# How to SFTP on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, sftp

I installed Amazon AMI 1.0 and logged in as `ec2-user` with key.
Then I ssh and set a password with `sudo passwd ec2-user`

But now when I connect via SFTP I get: `Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available`.
I use elastic IP and username ec2-user to connect.

Comment: What have you done to try and solve your own problem?

Answer (score 1):

If your SFTP program is able to use public keys it is possible to use the service without password.

> setup a passwd if run $sudo bash it will take to root #

`sudo -s` is permanent su, from there it is possible to use passwd.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely need to SFTP in as root, [Juan Hernandez's answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230516/sshing-into-ec2-server-via-gives-error-please-login-as-the-ec2-user-user-rather-t) will help:

> The message "Please login as the ec2-user user rather than root user." is displayed because a command is executed when you login with the private key. To remove that command edit `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file and remove the command option.

Thanks Juan!

Answer (score 0):

For ec2-user you need to setup a passwd if run `$sudo bash` it will take to root `#`

Comment: What is my root password?

Comment: you dont need root passwd when you run $sudo bash it not ask you passwd it will take to root

Answer (score 0):

For a long time I had a problem using PUTTY to login to my AWS instance using my chosen keypair. It was only when i realised that in the PUTTY GUI under "Auth" there is a subfolder, if you indavertently click on that instead of "Auth" you will see a similarly looking file entry field. If you load the keypair with that you will always get a connection error.