# Amazon to non-Amazon Data transfer

Tags: amazon-ec2

What is the best/fastest way of transferring data from an Amazon EC2 server to a non-Amazon server? Windows to Windows.

Comment: It can help to explain what you're trying to achieve. Why does it need to be fast? How much data are you transferring? Are there security or reliability requirements? What about costs? How do you define "best"?

Answer (score 2):

If your EC2 instance is in the default security group, you should be able to use SFTP or FTP over SSH out of the box.

**Related:**

- [Install and Configure an FTP server in an EC2 instance](http://linuxadminzone.com/install-and-configure-ftp-server-in-amazon-ec2-instance/)
- [How do you get data in and out of an EC2 instance?](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/support/20100413/how-do-you-get-data-and-out-ec2-instance)
- [How to SFTP on Amazon EC2](https://serverfault.com/questions/218148/how-to-sftp-on-amazon-ec2)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how large your data is. For very large datasets, there is [Amazon Import/Export](http://aws.amazon.com/importexport/) and a section of that page is titled "When to Use AWS Import/Export" and it describes how long it might take to transer data over 100GB in and out of Amazon EC2. There is also [Amazon Direct Connect](http://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/) that can give you a fat pipe to the US-East region.

If you referring smaller amounts of data, you might want to consider uploading to an S3 bucket and then downloading that from your non-Amazon workstation.

Answer (score 1):

## Amazon Direct Connect

http://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/

> AWS Direct Connect makes it easy to establish a dedicated network
>   connection from your premises to AWS. Using AWS Direct Connect, you
>   can establish private connectivity between AWS and your datacenter,
>   office, or colocation environment, which in many cases can reduce your
>   network costs, increase bandwidth throughput, and provide a more
>   consistent network experience than Internet-based connections.

Not the cheapest, but the fastest and arguably the best as it's a direct connection so you bypass the jungle that is the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is not very critical you can use ftp. Make one a ftp server and the other a client. The benefit is ftp also supports resume, helpful in case the data transfer is interrupted.